# IIS URL Rewrite Module root directory mapping

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I am using the URL Rewrite Module on IIS 8.

I want to be able to map all calls to *.archive to a page handler which *does work* using the following code

```
<rule name="Redirect .archive extension" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*).archive" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).archive$" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>          
          <action type="Rewrite" url="PageHandler.ashx?path={C:1}" />
        </rule>
```

I now need to map calls to directories / paths to the same handler where a default file is not specified e.g.

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/images
https://www.example.com/images/
```

Does anyone have any example about how I can achieve the above and keep my archive rule?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You could try to use this rule `<rule name="Redirect .archive extension" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)" />
          </conditions>          
          <action type="Rewrite" url="page1.html?path={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>` note:modify rewrite url as per your requirement.

Comment: That works awesome thanks; just one question, is it possible to only use it for sub-directories only? e.g; Calls to https://www.example.com will use the default document?

Comment: yes you could do that i will modify the solution and post it as an answer.

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="Redirect .archive extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="www.sample1.com/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)" />
      </conditions>          
      <action type="Rewrite" url="page1.html?path={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

Note:
Modify hostname and rewrite url as per your requirement.

[image]

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa